# NuGet MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.0 crashes in .Net "Framework" 4.8

Tags: mstest, .net-4.8

**Edited: as @Diego Malanij pointed out in answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74768591/4489263 it's the MSTest.TestAdapter 3.0.0 package causing the following observed misbehavior, whereas MSTest.TestFramework 3.0.0 works well**

*After* updating NuGet packages in a .Net 4.8 solution, MS UnitTests just reproducibly stopped working here in Visual Studio 2022 "Community Edition" on Windows 10 without having changed anything in the custom solution itself.
The same update(s) work well in a .Net6.0 solution

```
UnitTests

Updates:

MSTest.TestFramework.2.2.10 -> MSTest.TestFramework.3.0.0
MSTest.TestAdapter.2.2.10 -> MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.0
```

The Output window in the .Net4.8 solution shows exceptions, and the Test Explorer says:

```
UnitTests
  Tests in group: 134

Outcomes
   134 Not Run
```

**Output Window :**

> ========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 127 ms ==========

> Log level is set to Informational (Default).
> Source code repository not available. Some features may not work as expected.
> Connected to test environment '< Local Windows Environment >'
> Test data store opened in 0,139 sec.
> ========== Starting test discovery ==========
> No test is available in D:\Dev.Net\ProdSW\RingManager\RingManager\RingManager.Data\bin\Debug\RingManager.Data.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> No test is available in D:\Dev.Net\ProdSW\RingManager\RingManager\RingManager\bin\Debug\RingManager.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> No test is available in D:\Dev.Net\ProdSW\RingManager\RingManager\RingManager.CommonViews\bin\Debug\RingManager.CommonViews.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> No test is available in D:\Dev.Net\ProdSW\RingManager\RingManager\RingManager.Common\bin\Debug\RingManager.Common.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> ========== Test discovery finished: 134 Tests found in 3 sec ==========
> ========== Starting test run ==========
> ========== Test run finished: 134 Tests (134 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 16,7 sec ==========
> Starting test discovery for requested test run
> ========== Starting test discovery ==========
> ========== Test discovery finished: 134 Tests found in 1,7 sec ==========
> ========== Starting test run ==========
> An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Stack trace:
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.TestDeployment.GetDeploymentInformation(String source)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTestsInSource(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, String source, Boolean isDeploymentDone) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTests(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, Boolean isDeploymentDone)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, TestRunCancellationToken runCancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.RunTestsWithTests.InvokeExecutor(LazyExtension`2 executor, Tuple`2 executorUri, RunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.b__0()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.Run(Action action, PlatformApartmentState apartmentState, Boolean waitForCompletion)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.TryToRunInStaThread(Action action, Boolean waitForCompletion)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(IEnumerable`1 executorUriExtensionMap, Int64 totalTests)

========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 127 ms ==========

**After reverting the changes via version control system - *and restarting VS* - all is back to normal.**
So I guess I'll wait a little and then might try again with a next NuGet version, and this is more a warning than a question asking for help

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvisualstu-10/745548

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks, interesting! - the solution  _"problem turned out to be: I'd added a log4net configuration in app.config, but didn't have a configsections XML node that described the log4net section."_ sounds different to this case though, where the solution itself was unchanged and undoing the NuGet update apparently cured the symptom ... or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Does not seem to be a real question. May have value, but not as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.1` now being available apparently cures the symptom, may have been a temporary bug in its version `3.0.0`.
After installing NuGet

```
Updates:
MSTest.TestFramework.3.0.0 -> MSTest.TestFramework.3.0.1
MSTest.TestAdapter.2.2.10 -> MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.1
```

... all seems to be okay again

Comment: I was away for a while, but indeed, `MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.1` fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: Gracias @DiegoMalanij , funny that it looks as if not so extremely many other people added their flags, isn't it? IOW, if there possibly might have been individual local PC circumstances causing it, we might never know

Comment: You're welcome. I was not able to reproduce it easily to pin it down to a specific configuration. My personal laptop with VS 2019 Community worked fine, but my work installation with VS 2019 Pro didn't; when trying to narrow the scenario my personal computer died so that prevented me further examination; eventually found the hotfix published and stopped looking for the root cause. Checking the release notes the only thing that seems the possible solution for what we saw is [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/pull/1477)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the same issue with my solution. Today I was able to dig a bit deeper with fusion log and the problem is that the assembly is being searched in the *appbase* for the *testhost*, rather than the location of the unit test output itself (meaning `bin\debug` or `bin\release`).

I've taken a look at the `MSTest.TestAdapter` package itself and its props... it has changed the structure regarding the previous version, and now it contains the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework` assembly (which is loaded from the `packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.3.0.0\build\net462` location), but the extensions are no there.

I tried copying the missing *dll* in that location and tests execution succeeded, however that's clearly not a solution.

In my case this is with Visual Studio 2019, and I thought 2022 might have this solved but clearly after finding your post, that's not the case; I'll try to go a bit further with the analysis later, but as for now the only option is not updating the `MSTest.TestAdapter` package (the `MSTest.TestFramwork` is fine at *3.0.0*).

Comment: Yes, confirmed, MSTest.TestFramework is fine at 3.0.0, it's the MSTest.TestAdapter package causing the observed misbehavior, Thank you!

Comment: I still found this a bit puzzling, but assessing its root cause can be bit tedious (at least for me, not knowing how it has been designed). I've tried the same thing with my personal PC (different VS edition and therefore version) and it works fine... 

Will give it another try tomorrow at work to see if I can pin the behaviour before submitting an issue to their repository.